# Can somebody make sense of that crash in Monotouch 5.2.6 happening with SGen on?

Tags: c#, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

Randomly I'm getting the crash below in the iOS5 Simulator with Monotouch 5.2.6 and SGen being enabled. This is a debug build.
It is happening after clicking a button. That click spins off a new thread that shows a little progress indicator. When it is done thinking, it will exchange two views with animation (running all this on the UI thread).

I would like to know where to start because I don't get a managed stack trace. Am I right that it is trying to layout a UITableViewCell that no longer exists?

```
Native stacktrace:

    0   MobileApp                    0x00094fbc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
    1   MobileApp                    0x0000be72 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 178
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c5ee59b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   QuartzCore                          0x04176891 -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 89
    5   QuartzCore                          0x0417982d _ZL12actionForKeyP7CALayerPN2CA11TransactionEP8NSString + 82
    6   QuartzCore                          0x0417c9c3 _ZN2CA5Layer12begin_changeEPNS_11TransactionEjRP11objc_object + 131
    7   QuartzCore                          0x04181f82 _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 388
    8   QuartzCore                          0x04178205 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 68
    9   QuartzCore                          0x04177cba -[CALayer setFrame:] + 675
    10  UIKit                               0x021d8590 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 198
    11  UIKit                               0x022e1731 -[UILabel setFrame:] + 233
    12  UIKit                               0x02439731 -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager layoutSubviewsOfCell:] + 4511
    13  UIKit                               0x02390e34 -[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews] + 2650
    14  UIKit                               0x021e3322 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 178
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x011d6e72 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0417392d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 266
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0417d827 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 231
    18  QuartzCore                          0x04103fa7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 377
    19  QuartzCore                          0x04105ea6 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 374
    20  QuartzCore                          0x041059d3 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 65
    21  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c5dfe0c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 85
    22  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c59864c _pthread_exit + 146
    23  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c5989a0 pthread_exit + 33
    24  MobileApp                    0x0020434e thread_exit + 30
    25  MobileApp                    0x00203d03 thread_start_routine + 163
    26  MobileApp                    0x001aeb20 gc_start_thread + 80
    27  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c596ed9 _pthread_start + 335
    28  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c59a6de thread_start + 34
```

Comment: not sure it is trying to layout something... to me it seems to accessing some delegate which points nowhere... what exactly is the thread doing ? Is it by any chance creating or disposing of some UI objects ?

Comment: No explicit dispose. And yes, it is generating UI objects. It is removing a controller and its view from screen and adds another one.

Comment: I suspect some problem with interacting between the thread spawned by the button click and the UI thread... but it is hard to toll from that stack trace alone...

Comment: Ok, this is like a looong shot, I had this problem with monomac and it was because I was creating a menubar in a delegate that was called once after the the ctr... what I did was declare the menubar as a private attribute and just "instancing" there it there....

Answer (score 0):

Native code is trying to access something that has been freed.

This is the key line:

```
4   QuartzCore                          0x04176891 -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 89
```

you need to figure out what [CALayer actionForKey:] is trying to do (and on which object) - have in mind that this can be a number of things (calling a delegate / event, calling a virtual method, fetching a property). It's however difficult to be specific without seeing your actual code.